# Compare hundreds of rows of data against one in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an interesting problem that is actually causing me so much grief.

I have 2 tables that are identical in makeup. One table holds winning lottery numbers for a given draw, the other holds 500 randomly generated "tickets" for that draw.

I am trying to write some code that will tell me how many of the 500 tickets have 3 matching numbers, 4 matching numbers, 5 matching numbers and of course all 6 matching numbers.

the table structure for both tables is

id, playDate, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6.

Here is where I'm at and I know this isn't correct before anyone says anything. Really struggling here:

```
SELECT count(*) AS c, w.*, l.* 
FROM winningNums AS w, lottoNums AS l
WHERE w.playDate = "2016-10-10"
AND l.playDate = "2016-10-10"
AND l.num1 (
w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6 
)
```

I've also been batting something like this around

```
SELECT * 
FROM winningNums AS w
INNER JOIN lottoNums AS l
ON w.playDate = l.playDate
AND w.num1 = l.num1
AND w.num2 = l.num2
AND w.num3 = l.num3
AND w.num4 = l.num4
AND w.num5 = l.num5
AND w.num6 = l.num6
```

The main problem i'm facing is that a 3-match win could come from num1, num3, and num4 (from the ticket) matching up with num2, num5 and num6 (from the winning numbers).

Help :-)

Comment: normalize your data instead have two columns playDate and lottoNumbrer have six rows for each playDate. Then your join is simple.

Comment: Agree with @Niagaradad - this is a classic example of data normalization.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean guys but at least it's a lead. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll go study normalisation. Not come across that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT l.*,
    (l.num1 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6)) +
    (l.num2 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6)) +
    (l.num3 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6)) +
    (l.num4 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6)) +
    (l.num5 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6)) +
    (l.num6 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6))
    AS hits
FROM winningNums AS w
CROSS JOIN lottoNums AS l
WHERE w.playDate = "2016-10-10"
  AND l.playDate = "2016-10-10"
HAVING hits >= 3
ORDER BY hits DESC
```

This will compare every number from ticket with every number from lottery. And all hits/matches will be added.

Comment: This looked great but getting this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+
    l.num2 IN (w.num1, w.num2, w.num3, w.num4, w.num5, w.num6) +
    l.num3 IN' at line 2"

Comment: Some missing parenthesis, but now this seems to be working all good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN statement to find your matches which returns a 1 or zero then add them up to count number of matches...
And then using HAVING to check for matches >= 3 like this.

```
SELECT lot.id as lotid,draw.id as drawid,
     (draw.num1 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   + (draw.num2 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   + (draw.num3 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   + (draw.num4 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   + (draw.num5 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   + (draw.num6 IN (lot.num1,lot.num2,lot.num3,lot.num4,lot.num5,lot.num6))
   AS matches
FROM lot
  INNER JOIN draw
HAVING matches >= 3;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad7ff3/11)